# Earth moving over the Sun instead of around

Tags: kinematics, celestial-mechanics

Let's say you are observing the movement of the Sun and Earth from very far away. After year 1, the Earth creates an orbital plane around the Sun. Since the objects in the universe induce forces of different magnitudes on the Earth and Sun, you will observe the Sun and Earth moving differently, although the Earth will always orbit the Sun. My question is, what is the time frame under which the Earth moves out of the orbital plane it created after year 1. After how long does this orbital plane rotate? Will this change in orbital plane have any visual or physical effect for an observer on the Earth?

Comment: Jon, I suspect that you have some picture in your head. A picture where that magnetic pencil (what's that?) causes some process and makes things change. But the rest of us don't share that picture and as it stands this question is quite nonsensical.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The pencil isn't making anything change, it is just hypothetically drawing the Earths orbit on the Sun. I figured that the forces acting on the Sun and Earth from the other objects in the universe are different, and so to an outside observer instead of the Sun being to the `left' or `right' of the Earth it will eventually be `above' or below.' Does this make zero sense?

Comment: This makes zero sense. Earth already orbits out of the Sun's equatorial plane. And it rotates about an axis that is also no aligned with this orbital plane. But Earth will never be in a polar orbit around the Sun, so we will never see it as above or below us as in North and South. To an outside observer, all they have to do is rotate their head to change left-right to up-down

Comment: My question is, for an outside observer, how long does it take for the Earth to move out of its current orbital plane of rotation around the Sun?

Comment: The Earth precesses (on a roughly 26k year timescale) and nutates to a small degree causing the axial tilt to vary a bit. That latter causes the tropics to move north and south a little. The Earth's orbit also precesses a little and suffers modest changes in eccentricity over long time scales due to interactions with the other planets. But none of those effects are going to pull the Earth out of the ecliptic or cause it to turn over or reverse it's rotation.

Comment: I don't know that this question is particularly good, but at this point I don't feel right having it closed my moderator fiat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane of the earth's orbit is extremely stable.  Of course, the earth's orbit is affected by the other planets, especially Jupiter, but all the planets orbit in approximately the same plane, so the forces pulling the earth's orbit out of its plane are small.

We can see that the planes of the planets' orbit are stable, because all the planets are in roughly the same plane after 4.5 billion years, and it is approximately the same plane as the sun's rotation, so  it was determined by the angular momentum of the cloud from which the entire solar system formed.

A big change in the orbital plane of a planet *could* be caused by a close encounter with Jupiter.  This may have happened early on - indeed planets may have been ejected from the Solar system altogether.

> Will this change in orbital plane have any visual or physical effect for an observer on the Earth?

Let's imagine that some slow and non-catastrophic process causes the earth's orbital plane to rotate by 90º.  We need to ask: what happens to the earth's rotation axis?  If it stays the same (and why would  it change?), then the effects would be dramatic, as the axis is now approximately in the plane of the orbit, pointing almost directly towards the sun twice a year.  The whole of northern hemisphere would be in daylight for several months in the "summer", then in darkness during the "winter".